# How to select records corresponding to the first row in each group where no concept of minimum exists?

Tags: mysql, group-by

My table follows the following structure

```
+--------+---------+---------------------+--------------------+
| userId | loginId | tstamp              | action             |
+--------+---------+---------------------+--------------------+
| 134088 | NE78MEZ | 2014-10-31 13:59:33 | pageview           |
| 134088 | NE78MEZ | 2014-10-31 13:59:53 | pageview           |
| 134088 | NE78MEZ | 2014-10-31 14:00:26 | pageview           |
| 134088 | NE78MEZ | 2014-10-31 14:00:28 | pageview           |
| 134088 | 9T3CgQ7 | 2014-10-31 14:33:27 | pageview           |
| 134088 | 9T3CgQ7 | 2014-10-31 14:33:27 | pageview           |
| 134088 | 9T3CgQ7 | 2014-10-31 14:46:47 | pageview           |
| 134088 | tq69c8F | 2014-10-31 15:09:02 | pageview           |
| 134088 | tq69c8F | 2014-10-31 15:09:40 | ask                |
| 134088 | tq69c8F | 2014-10-31 15:10:34 | tag                |
| 134088 | tq69c8F | 2014-10-31 15:10:38 | tag                |
| 134088 | tq69c8F | 2014-10-31 15:10:45 | tag                |
| 134088 | tq69c8F | 2014-10-31 15:10:59 | rating             |
| 134088 | tq69c8F | 2014-10-31 15:11:09 | rating             |
| 134088 | tq69c8F | 2014-10-31 15:11:12 | pageview           |
| 134088 | tq69c8F | 2014-10-31 15:11:20 | tag                |
| 134088 | tq69c8F | 2014-10-31 15:11:29 | tag                |
| 134088 | tq69c8F | 2014-10-31 15:13:55 | rating             |
+--------+---------+---------------------+--------------------+
```

For each user (I have just one user in the example below), I have different login ids that are randomly generated ids representing different login sessions. For such randomly generated strings, the concept of minimum(loginId) doesn't make sense. But for each user, I want to pick all records corresponding to the first loginId.

So, I want the output to be something like:

```
+--------+---------+---------------------+--------------------+
| userId | loginId | tstamp              | action             |
+--------+---------+---------------------+--------------------+
| 134088 | NE78MEZ | 2014-10-31 13:59:33 | pageview           |
| 134088 | NE78MEZ | 2014-10-31 13:59:53 | pageview           |
| 134088 | NE78MEZ | 2014-10-31 14:00:26 | pageview           |
| 134088 | NE78MEZ | 2014-10-31 14:00:28 | pageview           |
```

for the user with userId 134088, followed by the next user in the list.

One way I can think of, is to create a column called session id that is the "numeric" version of the randomly generated loginId and use `where session=1` with a `group by userId` clause. Is there a way I can get around without creating this redundant column?

I am trying to do this in mysql

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by finding the minimum time stamp and then choosing all the logins associated with that.  This would be much easier with window/analytic functions, but in MySQL:

```
select t.*
from mytable t join
     (select t2.userid, substring_index(group_concat(t2.loginid order by timestamp), ',', 1) as firstlogin
      from mytable t2
      group by t2.userid
     ) t2
     on t.userid = t2.userid and t.login = t2.firstlogin;
```

The `substring_index()`/`group_concat()` is a trick in MySQL to get the login associated with the first timestamp.  This saves some extra `join` logic or having to use variables.